# javascript input selectedIndex no funciona

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero seleccionar una "option" dentro de un "select" usando selectedIndex de JavaScript, pero no funciona. Ósea quiero que una opción de una lista desplegable se seleccione cuando se cargue una pagina. Aquí les muestro el código HTML:

```
        <select id="periodicidad" name="periodicidad" class="form-control" onChange="periodicidadChange()" >
          <option value="">Seleccione periodicidad</option>
          <option value="1">Periódico</option>
          <option value="0.7">Permanente</option>
          <option value="0.3">Eventual</option>
        </select>
```

Para hacer la selección uso el siguiente código JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  document.getElementById("periodicidad").selectedIndex = "<?php echo $periodicidad_valor; ?>";
});
```

La variable PHP "$periodicidad_valor" entrega el valor "0.7". Si imprimo esa variable en un "input" se obtiene el siguiente codigo:

```
<input id="periodicidad2" name="periodicidad2" type="text" class="form-control" value="0.7" readonly />
```

También probé la función devolviendo el valor "0,7", pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: En la función: `document.getElementById("periodicidad")`... en el input: `id="periodicidad2"` Veo difícil que lo encuentre si las id no coinciden!

Comment: @Benito-B El input que tiene como id="periocidad2" es un ejemplo para que vean que devuelve la variable $periodicidad_valor. Lo que quiero es seleccionar la opción con valor "0.7" del select de mas arriba.

Comment: @BetaM Quiero que en la lista desplegable se vea esa opción como la seleccionada. Creo que para eso sirve selectedIndex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NikolaTesla gracias por darme la pista para encontrar la solución a mi problema. Remarco que el problema es que quiero seleccionar una opción de la lista desplegable por un valor que viene del servidor ($periodicidad_valor). la solución que seria la siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var periodicidadValor = "<?php echo $periodicidad_valor; ?>";
  var periodicidadOpcion = 0;
  switch (periodicidadValor) {
    case "1":
      periodicidadOpcion = 1;
    break;
    case "0.7":
      periodicidadOpcion = 2;
    break;
    case "0.3":
      periodicidadOpcion = 3;
    break;
  }
  const periodicidadSelect = document.querySelector('#periodicidad');
  periodicidadSelect.options[periodicidadOpcion].setAttribute('selected',true);
});
</script>
<select id="periodicidad" name="periodicidad" class="form-control" >
  <option value="">Seleccione periodicidad</option>
  <option value="1">Periódico</option>
  <option value="0.7">Permanente</option>
  <option value="0.3">Eventual</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que para obtener el `index` del elemento seleccionado, este lo debes de capturar en el evento `change` de tu select, ejemplo:

```
//ACCEDEMOS A TU SELECT A TRAVES DE SU ID
const select = document.querySelector('#periodicidad');

//AGREGAMOS EL CHANGE AL SELECT
select.addEventListener('change',() =>{
  
  //ALMACENAMOS EN UNA VARIABLE EL INDEX ELEMENTO SELECCIONADO
  let index = select.selectedIndex;
  
  //MOSTRAMOS POR CONSOLA EL INDEX DEL ELEMENTO SELECCIONADO
  
  console.log(index);
  
})
```

Veo que ya tienes un evento change en tu select, deberías de capturar el valor dentro de esa función. Si deseas **testear** el código anterior, deberás quitar ese evento que tienes en el select, quedando tu HTML así:

```
<select id="periodicidad" name="periodicidad" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Seleccione periodicidad</option>
          <option value="1">Periódico</option>
          <option value="0.7">Permanente</option>
          <option value="0.3">Eventual</option>
        </select>
```

Para que puedas testearlo sin problema.

2.- Si ya sabes que opción quieres modificar, considera utilizar `options` y le indicas el índice al que deseas acceder, ejemplo:

```
//ACCEDEMOS A TU SELECT A TRAVES DE SU ID
const select = document.querySelector('#periodicidad');

 //MOSTRAMOS POR CONSOLA EL VALOR DE LA OPCION CON INDICE 2
console.log(select.options[2].value);
```

3.- Te muestro un ejemplo de lo que quieres realizar:

```js
//ACCEDEMOS A TU SELECT A TRAVES DE SU ID
const select = document.querySelector('#periodicidad');

 //A LA OPCION CON INDICE 2 LE PONEMOS EL ATRIBUTO SELECTED
select.options[2].setAttribute('selected',true);
```

```html
<select id="periodicidad" name="periodicidad" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Seleccione periodicidad</option>
          <option value="1">Periódico</option>
          <option value="0.7">Permanente</option>
          <option value="0.3">Eventual</option>
        </select>
```

4.- Aunque en realidad no necesitas *javascript* para realizar esa accion, puedes poner directamente **selected** en la **opcion** que deseas que aparezca por defecto seleccionada. Ejemplo:

```html
<select id="periodicidad" name="periodicidad" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Seleccione periodicidad</option>
          <option value="1">Periódico</option>
  <!-- NOTA QUE PONEMOS SELECTED A LA OPCION QUE QUEREMOS QUE APAREZCA SELECCIONADA POR DEFECTO-->        
  <option value="0.7" selected>
    Permanente
  </option>
          <option value="0.3">Eventual</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Pero no quiero obtener el value del select. Solo quiero seleccionar una opción de la lista desplegable (que ya tiene opciones estáticas) para que esta se esta vea cuando cargue una página.

Comment: @WalterCorpus El **.value** Solo fue un ejemplo, de lo que puedes hacer, ya que con **select.options[2]** Ya estarás seleccionando la opcion con ese indice, con un poco mas de imaginación podrias haber resuelto tu duda. Actualice mi respuesta para que veas como puedes realizar lo que planteas. Saludos.